# How to find orders per work hour of each employee per day

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, count, dataset

I have three tables. The first one is called 'Orders' where the order dates are stored along with the employee that handled the orders.

| order_date | employee_id |
| --- | --- |
| 01/08/2015 | 101 |
| 01/08/2015 | 101 |
| 01/08/2017 | 102 |
| 01/08/2017 | 119 |

The second table is called 'Employee_Hours'. This is where the total duration of work time per employee is stored per day.

| employee_id | total_work_in_seconds | shift_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1900 | 01/08/2015 |
| 118 | 1850 | 01/08/2015 |
| 119 | 2250 | 01/08/2017 |

The third table is 'Employees'. This is where the employee names and id are stored.

| name | employee_id |
| --- | --- |
| John Doe | 101 |
| Jane Doe | 118 |
| Will Drake | 102 |
| Caleb White | 119 |

How do you find the orders per work hour of each employee? Ideally the query should result in something like (the values are arbitrary):

| employee_id | name | shift_date | order_per_work_hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | John Doe | 01/08/2015 | 2.5 |
| 118 | Jane Doe | 01/08/2015 | 3 |
| 101 | John Doe | 01/08/2017 | 3.5 |
| 119 | Caleb White | 01/08/2017 | 1.5 |

I am aware that in order to get the order per work hour for each employee per day, you'd have to first divide *total_work_in_seconds* by 3600 and then use this to divide the counted orders of the employee for that specific day. The problem is I do not know how to translate the code into SQL statement. I also know that it would require three JOIN statements.

Additionally, for the order dates there are only two unique dates in the table which are `01/08/2015` and `01/08/2017`.

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: When did `Jane Doe` get an order? Are you sure your question is correct?

Comment: So far I have tried `SELECT Orders.empoyee_id, Employees.name, Orders.order_date, COUNT(Orders.employee_id) AS Num_Orders,
 FROM Orders JOIN  Employees ON Orders.employee_id = Employees.employee_id JOIN Employee_Hours ON Employees.employee_id = Employee_Hours.employee_id
 GROUP BY Orders.order_date_local, Employees.employee_name`. As for the `Jane Doe` order, the values in the table are arbitrary and the actual tables are much larger, but essentially the problem lies in formulating the proper query to produce the last table.

Comment: it's not clear from context relation between table "orders" and "employee_hours". Do I understand correctly that order_date == shift_date? Need more details about structure your data.

Comment: Yes, the order_date == shift_date, as each order is processed by an employee.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [Help] PS [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```sql
WITH o AS (
SELECT
  employee_id,
  order_date,
  COUNT(employee_id) AS num_orders
FROM `dataset.Orders`
GROUP BY employee_id, order_date
)
SELECT
  o.employee_id,
  e.name,
  h.shift_date,
  SAFE_DIVIDE(o.num_orders, h.total_work_in_seconds/3600) AS order_per_work_hour
FROM o
LEFT JOIN `dataset.Employee_Hours` h ON o.employee_id=h.employee_id AND o.order_date=h.shift_date
LEFT JOIN `dataset.Employees` e ON o.employee_id=e.employee_id
```

Nevertheless I haven't tested it because I don't have similar data in my BQ.

I supposed you need a left join because your expected output have only workers who took orders but if that is not the case you can use the type of join that better fits your needs.